# Can't write Jasmine tests for the module pattern

Tags: jasmine

I am trying to use Jasmine to test a simple JavaScript class but I have not been able to determine why the test fails.

```
    // Define the class to be tested

    function Quiz() {
        // private variables
        var score = 1;

        function getScore() {
            return score;
        }

        // public methods
        return {
            getScore: getScore
        };
    }
```

Before running the test verify that the getScore method can be called.

```
    // Get the score outside of the Jasmine test
    var myQuiz = new Quiz();
    var myScore = myQuiz.getScore();
    console.log("myScore = ", myScore);
```

Now try running the test

```
    describe("A Quiz", function() {
        it("should have a default score of 1", function() {
            // Get the score inside of the Jasmine test
            var quiz = new Quiz();
            console.log("Quiz object: ", quiz);
            var score = quiz.getScore();
            console.log("score", score);
            expect(score).toBe(1);
        });

    });
```

Here is the output from running the test.

```
A Quiz should have a default score of 1.
    ✘ TypeError: quiz.getScore is not a function in http://localhost:7357/scripts/QuizTest.js (line 26)
        @http://localhost:7357/scripts/QuizTest.js:26
myScore =  1
Quiz object:  {"score":0}
```

Before I run the test, I verify that the getScore method is callable. The last line in the output is from the console.log statement before the test. This verifies that getScore can be found.

However, if I try to call the getScore method inside the Jasmine test, it is not found. Logging the quiz object verifies that only the score variable and no method are visible.

```
Why can't Jasmine see the method?
```

Answer (score 0):

he does not think the function getScore because you are inside Quiz (), you can solve by using parameter or global variable, you can also return the Quiz function () +1 score, or declare it in one var parameter passing, or feeding a global Score